# Lambda function using a delegate

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda

I have the following:

```
class Program {

    delegate int myDelegate(int x);

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Program p = new Program();
        Console.WriteLine(p.writeOutput(3, new myDelegate(x => x*x)));

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    private string writeOutput(int x, myDelegate del) {
        return string.Format("{0}^2 = {1}",x, del(x));
    }
}
```

Is the method `writeOutput` in the above required? Can the following be re-written, without `writeoutput`, to output the same as the above?

Can the line `Console.WriteLine("x^2 = {0}", new myDelegate(x => x*x));` be amended so that 3 is fed into the function?

```
class Program {

    delegate int myDelegate(int x);

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Program p = new Program();

        Console.WriteLine("x^2 = {0}", new myDelegate(x => x*x));

        Console.WriteLine("press [enter] to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you're practicing the use of delegates, I don't see why it would be necessary in your code. You have the value, and you know what to do with it.

Comment: @AndersonSilva - right the first time - I'm sand-pitting delegates and lambda functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It obviously can't be written that way. Think about this: what value *x* has in the second code? you create an instance of your delegate, but when it is called?

Use this code:

```
myDelegate myDelegateInstance = new myDelegate(x => x * x);
Console.WriteLine("x^2 = {0}", myDelegateInstance(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You fon't really need a delagate.
But in order to work you need to change this line:

```
    Console.WriteLine("x^2 = {0}", new myDelegate(x => x*x));
```

with this:

```
    Console.WriteLine("{0}^2 = {1}", x, x*x);
```

Comment: +1 thanks Petar - but the point of the exercise is that I'm trying to understand delegates and how lambdas relate to them

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you don't need a delegate. You can just multiply it directly. But first, the correction of the delegate.

```
myDelegate instance = x => x * x;
Console.WriteLine("x^2 = {0}", instance(3));
```

You should treat every instance of a delegate like a function, in the same way you do it in the first example. The `new myDelegate(/* blah blah */)` is not necessary. You can use a lambda directly.

I assume you're practicing the use of delegates/lambdas, because you could just have written this:

```
Console.WriteLine("x^2 = {0}", 3 * 3);
```

Comment: +1 exactly - just practicing delegates/lambda and trying to get my head around how they work